Cannot mount external hard drive
I have an external hard drive that was working about a week ago when I was running my desktop.  Today I used my desktop, and I could not access the hard drive.  I get the following error:
Unable to access "500 GB Volume"  
Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/john/C0AEFE04AEFDF2B0: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

I am running a dedicated Ubuntu 24.04.1 OS on a Geekom Mini IT12.  There is no dual boot.
I have tried running sudo ntfsfix according to some other posts that I've seen, but to no avail.


The real error is burried in the kernel logs.  Dig through /var/log/syslog around the time you try mounting the disk.  May be failing hardware or corrupt filesystem.  If the latter, and it really is ntfs, you might need to get windows to fix it.

This question is similar to: I can't open NTFS External HDD | mounting error. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you only have Ubuntu, you should not be using NTFS. NTFS will require chkdsk, defrag or other repairs that can only be done from Windows. The Linux ntfsfix only does a minor fix, and sets chkdsk flag so when rebooted into Windows it runs chkdsk to fix it. Did you use drive with a Windows system that then set hibernation flag, preventing normal mount with the Linux NTFS driver?
